# Making a supertitle over subplots using export_fig

Tags: matlab, export, subplot

I am using the FileExchange function `export_fig` to generate nicely looking pdf plots from Matlab. Until now it all worked well, but generating a 'supertitle' over my subplots seems to be hard. I tried using the FileExchange function `suplabel` but whenever I use it, after rendering it changes all my title fonts back to Courier. As an alternative solution I've tried placing a text box, but the same thing happened.

Here's an example code I made up to illustrate my problem:

```
figure;

for i=1:6

subplot(2,3,i)
t=0:0.01:6;
plot(t,sin(i*t))

hTitle  = title (sprintf('Sin(%dx)',i));
axis([0 max(t) -1 1])

set(gca                       , ...
    'FontName'   , 'Avant Garde' );
set([hTitle, hXLabel, hYLabel], ...
    'FontName'   , 'Avant Garde');
set([hXLabel, hYLabel]  , ...
    'FontSize'   , 12          );
set( hTitle                    , ...
    'FontSize'   , 13          , ...
    'FontWeight' , 'bold'      );
end

suplabel('Supertitle','t')

export_fig('-painters','-transparent','-r600','-pdf')
open export_fig_out.pdf
```

Main question here is if anyone knows how to easily work around this problem while remaining to use `export_fig`?